# What does "back off on" mean in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What does "back off on" mean in the following sentence?

> Stop eating bread, flour products, back off on eating a
>   lot of protein.

Does "back off on eating a lot of protein" mean "eat a lot of protein"?
or does "back off on eating a lot of protein" mean "do not eat a lot of protein"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase you are interesting in is

> **back off**

which means to "*withdraw from*", "*reduce*", or "*decrease*"

> *back off* on eating a lot of protein.
>   *reduce eating protein*

Comment: Google Translator translated "back off on eating a lot of protein" as "단백질을 많이 섭취하십시오(=eat a lot of protein)".  Google translator misinterpreted this too.

Comment: Why using "on" in "back off on"? What is the difference between "back off on eating a lot of protein" and "back off eating a lot of protein" ?

Comment: There is  no difference in understanding, it's stylistic. It could also be "back off *from* eating a lot of protein".